# $R$-Orientability of a Topological Manifold

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

Let $M$ be a $n$-manifold and $R$ a PID ring. $M$ is then called $R$- orientable if for each $x \in M$ there exists a family of generators $[M]_x \in H_n(M, M - \{x\}) \cong H_n(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n- \{x\}) \cong \widetilde{H}_{n-1}(S^{n-1}) \cong R$ of $R$ such that for every $x \in M$ there exist an open $U \subset M$ with $x \in U$ and an $\alpha \in H_n(M, M- U)$ with following property:

For every $ z \in U $we have that

$\alpha \mapsto [M]_z$ for the canonical map $H_n(M, M-U) \to H_n(M, M - \{z\}) $.

Therefore locally $\alpha$ is mapped to the choosen generators $[M]_z$.

Now my question:

Let $B \subset M$ a closed $n$- disc on $M$ (so $B \cong \overline{B_r(0)}$).

I want to show that $M$ is $R$-orientable $\Leftrightarrow$ $M\backslash B$ is $R$-orientable.

"$\Rightarrow$" is trivial. Now the problem is "$\Leftarrow$"

My idea was following: If $x \in M \backslash B$ that's ok since local problem. So wlog $x \in B$. If I can show that there exist a smaller $n$ disc $B_{r'}(0) \cong B' \subset B$ with $x \in B \backslash B'$ such that the $R$ orientation of $M \backslash B$ is extendable to $M \backslash B'$ then I win since $x$ was arbitrary but I don't see a way to get it.

Or does there exist another way to prove the statement?

Comment: The boundary of the disc has a tubular neighborhood, so $B$ actually sits inside a slightly larger open disc $B'$. You have an orientation on the open set $B' \setminus B$ already, which is $S^{n-1} \times (0, \epsilon)$, the annulus past the boundary of $B$. Your goal is to prove that an orientation on this annulus extends uniquely to an orientation of $B^n$.

Comment: @Mike Miller: Yes, that's true since that's a local problem. Could you give a hint / idea how to cope with it? Naively I would take a arbitrary $x \in B$ and consider a generator $\alpha \in H_n(M, M - x) \cong H_n(M, M -B')$. The choice of the family $[M]_x$ inside $B$ is induced by images of $\alpha$ by canonic map $H_n(M, M-B) \to H_n(M, M - \{x\})$. The problem is to prove the compatibitily on the annulus with given orientation on $M \backslash B$. Here I'm stuck.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're responding to with "Yes, that's true". If you mean the reduction outlined above, then you don't need to mention $M$ anymore; now you can just talk about $B^n$ and a neighborhood of the boundary. Here you should use that a connected orientable manifold carries exactly two orientations.

Comment: Yes, I meant the reduction step.

Comment: @MikeMiller Tubular neighborhoods only exist for smooth submanifolds of smooth manifolds. The question is about topological manifolds, so this technique does not apply. Consider for example the Alexander horned ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @KarlPeter What is the origin of your question?

Comment: @Paul Good point, though I object slightly to your phrasing: tubular neighborhoods are only *guaranteed* for smooth submanifolds. But then we can just restrict to an ever so slightly smaller disc. Clearly any radial sphere in $D^n$ other than the boundary admits a tubular neighborhood, with the 'neighborhood coordinate' being the radius.

Comment: Ah, but OP wants to work on the complement of this specific ball. Sure, that's a problem. I think wherever this is from probably intended this ball to be in the interior of another ball.

Comment: @MikeMiller I agree that we may define tubular neighborhoods of submanifolds $N \subset M$ also in the category of topological manifolds. I do not know whether topological submanifolds always have tubular neigborhoods, but the more serious problem is that the boundary of a topological disk in $M$ is not necessarily a submanifold.of $M$.

Comment: Concerning the "nested" disks: That is why I asked him to provide some context.

Comment: @PaulFrost When OP writes $B \subset M$ I assume that means the inclusion of $B$ is an embedding. The boundary is a submanifold (but as you observe potentially a wild one without a collar on both sides). Since the Alexander horned sphere is homeomorphic to the sphere you gave a counterexample earlier to the existence of a tubular neighborhood. /// It seems we are now in agreement about the question. Thank you for clarifying my remarks.

Comment: The Alexander horned sphere is a copy of $S^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but it is not a submanifold (it is not locally flat).

Comment: By the way, both of us focus on geometric arguments using "nicely"embedded disks. But I have the vague feeling that there are purely homological arguments which work for arbitrary disks. And I believe that there are various  interpretations of "submanifold" in the topological case. I understand it as a locally flat embedded object.

Comment: @Paul Frost: The origin was an exercise where I have to distinguish in which cases the manifold $M_1 \# M_2$ is orientable for given (indeed just topological) manifolds $M_1, M_2$. Here I intend to prove the statement: "$M$ is $R$-orientable $\Leftrightarrow$ $M\backslash B$ is $R$-orientable " as lemma to cover the case if  $M_1$ and $M_2$ are orientable.

Comment: @KarlPeter So the origin is the connected sum construction. In this case your closed disk $B$ can actually be chosen so that it is contained in a closed $B''$ such that $(B',B) \approx (\overline{B}_2(0), \overline{B}_1(0))$ (homeomorphism of pairs). Now Mike Miller's comments apply. Essentially you have to show that an orientation of $B_1(0)  \setminus 0$ extends to an orientation of  $B_1(0)$. You should write an official answer. Note that both manifolds are orientable and have exactly two distinct orientations. Then the argument should be obvious.

Comment: @Paul Frost: I'm not sure if I understood his hint correctly. I suppose that I can extend the orientation on $B' - B$ canonically by choosing a $x \in B' - B$. Then I guess that from here I have "no choice" for extending to $B$: Let $x' \in B$ then following isomorphisms make the job:$H_n(B', (B' -B)- x) \cong H_n(B', B' -B) \cong H_n(B, B-x')$ ...the first one holds by orientableness of $B' -B$ and the second one is the excision axiom. So I have "no other choice", right? Before I post that as an official answer I would like to know if that's a correct argument

Comment: @KarlPeter I must admit that I only have in mind $R = \mathbb{Z}$. Use the fact that connected orientable manifolds have exacatly two orientations corresponding to the two generators of $\mathbb{Z}$. You should consider $A  = int(B') \setminus B$ which is a manifold without boundary (in fact, it is an open annulus). An orientation is a family of compatible generators of $H_n(A, A \setminus x)$, and there are exactly two of them. The same holds true for $int(B')$. By excision $H_n(int(B'), int(B') \setminus x) \approx H_n(A, A \setminus x)$ for $x \in A$.

Comment: Thus each orientation $\omega'$ of $int(B')$ induces an orientation $\omega$ of $A$, and if $\omega_1' \ne \omega_2'$, then $\omega_1 \ne \omega_2$. For an arbitrary $R$ I believe that you get an orientation for each generator of $R$. This would allow to generalize the above argument.

Answer (score 1):

Let us prove

Theorem 1. Let $M$ be a manifold and  $M_1, M_2$ be open subsets (hence they are also manifolds). Assume that $M_1, M_2$ are orientable and $M_1 \cap M_2$ is connected. Then $M$ is orientable.

This doesn't apply exactly to your question concerning  the complement of a closed disk in $M$, but if you read the comments, you will see that this is probably the best what can be done ($M_2$ is an open disk and $M_1 \cap M_2$ an annulus). Anyway it suffices to treat connected sums.

Let us now introduce the concept of an *orientation*.

Let $\omega = (\omega_x)_{x \in M}$ be a a family of generators $\omega_x$ of $H_n(M,M \setminus x) \approx R$. Then for any two $x, z \in M$ we get a unique isomorphism $[\omega]^x_z : H_n(M,M \setminus x) \to H_n(M,M \setminus z)$ such that $[\omega]^x_z (\omega_x) = \omega_z$. Note we have $[\omega]^x_x = id$ and $[\omega]^z_y \circ [\omega]^x_z = [\omega]^x_y$.

We say that an open $U \subset M$ is *$\omega$-trivializing* if there exists an $\alpha \in H_n(M, M \setminus U)$ with the following property:

For every $z \in U$, $(i_U^z)_*(\alpha) = \omega_z$ (with the inclusion of pairs $i_U^z : (M, M \setminus U) \to (M, M \setminus z)$).

If each $x \in M$ has an open neighborhood $U$ which is $\omega$-trivializing, we call $\omega$ an *orientation* of $M$.

Clearly, a manifold is orientable if and only it has an orientation. However, it may have more than one.

Let us say that an open $U \subset M$ is *isomorphically trivializing* if $(i_U^z)_*$ is an isomorphism for all $z \in U$. Then for any two $x,z \in U$ we obtain an isomorphism $[U]^x_z = (i_U^z)_* \circ ((i_U^x)_*)^{-1} : H_n(M, M \setminus x) \to H_n(M, M \setminus z)$. This isomorphism is completely independent from any family of generators $\omega = (\omega_x)_{x \in M}$.

Lemma 1. For each $x \in M$ and each open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ in $M$ there exists an open neighborhood $U \subset V$ of $x$ which is isomorphically trivializing.

Proof. Using a chart around $x$ we find a homeomorphism $h : B_{2r}(0) \to V' \subset V$ such that $V'$ is open in $M$ and $h(0) = x$. Define $U = h(B_r(0))$. It is easy to see that the inclusion $j^z_U : M \setminus U \to  M \setminus z$ is a homotopy equivalence for all $z \in U$ (in fact, $M \setminus U$ is a strong deformation retract of $M \setminus z$). We have $i^z_U = (id_M,j^z_U) : (M, M \setminus U ) \to (M, M \setminus x)$. Now $i^z_U$ induces homomorphisms connecting the long exact sequences of the pairs $(M, M \setminus U)$ and $(M, M \setminus z)$. But all $(id_M)_*$ and all $(j^z_U)_*$ are isomorphisms (on all $H_k$), thus the five lemma proves that all $(i_U^x)_*$ are isomorphisms.

Lemma 2. Let $U \subset M$ be isomorphically trivializing. Then $U$ is $\omega$-trivializing if and only if $[\omega]^x_z = [U]^x_z$ for all $x, z \in U$.

Proof. Let $U$ be $\omega$-trivializing. Then there exists $\alpha \in H_n(M, M \setminus U)$ such that $(i_U^z)_*(\alpha) = \omega_z$ for all $z \in U$, i.e. $\alpha = ((i_U^z)_*)^{-1}(\omega_z)$ for all $z \in U$. But now $[U]^x_z(\omega_x) = (i_U^z)_*(((i_U^x)_*)^{-1}(\omega_x)) = (i_U^z)_*(\alpha) = \omega_z$, hence $[U]^x_z = [\omega]^x_z$. Conversely, let $[\omega]^x_z = [U]^x_z$ for all $x, z \in U$. For $x \in U$ define $\alpha_x = ((i_U^x)_*)^{-1}(\omega_x)$. Then $\omega_z = [\omega]^x_z(\omega_x) = [U]^x_z(\omega_x) = (i_U^z)_*(((i_U^x)_*)^{-1}(\omega_x)) = (i_U^z)_*(\alpha_x)$, i.e. $U$ is $\omega$-trivializing.

Let us say that an open $U \subset M$ is *strongly $\omega$-trivializing* if it is both $\omega$-trivializing and isomorphically trivializing. If $U$ is strongly $\omega$-trivializing, then for all $x, z \in U$ we have $[\omega]^x_z = [U]^x_z$ which shows that on $U$ the isomorphisms $[\omega]^x_z$ are independent of $\omega$.

Lemma 3. Let $V \subset M$ be $\omega$-trivializing. Then each isomorphically trivializing $U \subset V$ is strongly $\omega$-trivializing.

Proof. Let $\beta \in H_n(M, M \setminus V)$ such that for all $z \in V$, $(i_V^z)_*(\beta) = \omega_z$. Define $\alpha = j_*(\beta)$, where $j : M \setminus V \to M \setminus U$ denotes inclusion. Then for all $z \in U$, $(i_U^z)_*(\alpha) = \omega_z$.

Corollary 1. $\omega$ is a orientation if and only each $x \in M$ has an open neighborhood $U$ which is strongly $\omega$-trivializing.

Lemma 4. Let $\omega^1, \omega^2$ be orientations of $M$. Then the sets $E(\omega^1,\omega^2) = \{ x \in M \mid \omega^1_x = \omega^2_x \}$ and $N(\omega^1,\omega^2) = \{ x \in M \mid \omega^1_x \ne \omega^2_x \}$ are open in $M$.

Proof. For $x \in M$ choose $\omega^i$-trivializing open neighborhood $U_i$. $U_1 \cap U_2$ contains an isomorphically trivializing neighborhood $U$ of $x$. If $x \in E(\omega^1,\omega^2)$, then for $z \in U$ we get $\omega^1_z = [\omega^1]^x_z(\omega_x) = [U]^x_z(\omega^1_x) = [U]^x_z(\omega^2_x) = [\omega^2]^x_z(\omega^2_x) = \omega^2_z$, i.e. $U \subset E(\omega^1,\omega^2)$. The same argument applies for $x \in N(\omega^1,\omega^2)$.

Corollary 2. Two orientations $\omega^1, \omega^2$ of a connected manifold are equal if and only if $\omega^1_\xi = \omega^2_\xi$ for a single $\xi \in M$.

Now let $M$ be a manifold, $\xi \in M$ and $\omega$ be a family of generators. For each $g  \in G_\xi$ = set of generators of $H_n(M,M \setminus \xi)$ define a family of generators $\omega^{\xi,g} = (\omega^{\xi,g}_x)$ by $\omega^{\xi,g}_x = [\omega]^\xi_x(g)$. For $g = \omega_\xi$ we have $\omega^{\xi,g} = \omega$. Moreover, $\omega^{\xi,g}_\xi = g$ and $[\omega]^x_z(\omega^{\xi,g}_x) = [\omega]^x_z([\omega]^\xi_x(g)) = [\omega]^\xi_z(g) = \omega^{\xi,g}_z$ which implies $[\omega]^x_z = [\omega^{\xi,g}]^x_z$.

Lemma 5. Each strongly $\omega$-trivializing open $U \subset M$ is strongly $\omega^{\xi,g}$-trivializing. Thus, if $\omega$ is an orientation, then so is $\omega^{\xi,g}$.

Proof. For $x, z \in U$, $[(\omega^{\xi,g})]^x_z =  [(\omega)]^x_z = [U]^x_z$. Now Lemma 2 applies.

Corollary 3. Let $M$ be a connected manifold, $\xi \in M$ and $\omega$ be an orientation of $M$. Then the set of all orientations of $M$ is given as $\{ \omega^{\xi,g} \mid g \in G_\xi \}$. In other words, for each $g \in G_\xi$ there exists a unique orientation $\omega^{\xi,g}$ of $M$ such that $\omega^{\xi,g}_\xi = g$.

To prove Theorem 1 it clearly suffices to prove

Theorem 2. Let $M$ be an orientable manifold and $N \subset M$ be open and connected. Then each orientation of $M$ induces an orientation of $N$ (this is well-known) and each orientation of $N$ extends to an orientation of $M$.

Proof. It suffices to extend any orientation $\omega^N$ of $N$ to the component$M'$ of $M$ which contains $N$. All other components of $M$ can be oriented independently. Let $\xi \in N$. If $k : (N,N \setminus \xi) \to (M',M' \setminus \xi)$ denotes inclusion, we see by excision that $g = k_*(\omega^N_\xi)$ is a generator of $H_n(M',M' \setminus \xi)$. Since $M'$ is orientable, there exists a unique orientation $\omega^{\xi,g}$ of $M'$ such that $\omega^{\xi,g}_\xi = g$. Restriction induces an orientation $\omega^{\xi,g} \mid_N$ on $N$. But by construction $(\omega^{\xi,g} \mid_N)_\xi = \omega^N_\xi$ so that $\omega^{\xi,g} \mid_N = \omega^N$.